# Excel Formula or VBA to copy cells removing blanks?

Tags: excel, vba, cell, formula

I'm looking to copy cells A1:B100 to D1:E100 but removing blanks.. Would this be possible via a formula or would I have to use VBA?

Here's an example: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way to do it:

**Initial data:**

[image]

**Step1:** copy all data from `A:B`. Select `D1`, right mouse click and select *PasteSpecial->PasteValues*:

[image]

**Step2:** with selected range with data in columns `D:E` (in my case `D1:E8`) press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

[image]

**Step3:** in the `GoTo` dialog window press <kbd>Special...</kbd> and select *Blanks*

[image]

**Step4:** now all empty cells in `D1:E8` are selected.

[image]

**Step5:** right mouse click on amy *selected cell* and press *Delete*

[image]

**Step6:** select "Shift cells up" and press  *OK*. **Done!**

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

---

**UPD:** as follow up from comments, OP has `=IF(Sheet1!D11="YES",Sheet1!A11, "")` in `A:B`. And since `""` not actually blank cell, we can't use *Special->Blanks*.

There is VBA solution:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    'change sheet name to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'find lastrow in columns A:B
        lastrow = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, _
                                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        'Copy values from A:B to D:E
        .Range("D1:E" & lastrow).Value = .Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value
        'Iterates throught each cell in D:E and if it equals to "" - remember it
        For Each cell In .Range("D1:E" & lastrow)
            If cell.Value = "" Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = cell
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        'delete all empty cells (with "")
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this way, However I'm using a formula in A & B so it won't work :(

Comment: see my updated answer (STEP1). You could use *PasteSpecial->PasteValies* to paste only values in columns D:E

Comment: Thats what I'm doing, I'm pasting Values however when I come to delete the blanks Excel still thinks theirs something in the cell and I can't get my head around it. I'm using the code (at bottom) to pull data from sheet 1. =IF(Sheet1!D11="YES",Sheet1!A11, "")

Comment: @Jacko058, see my updated answer for VBA solution

Comment: Thank you, I got it working now.. Using Formula's & VBA can get complex at delecting the values :( Got it working but had to run through an extra 2 pages but its ok. Thank you though :) -Jacko

Answer (score 0):

1) First, before you make any drastic changes to any workbook always make sure you have a backup copy or a recently saved copy in case you need to restore the original data.

2) Now, select the cells in one column from the top of your list to the bottom.

3) Make sure that all the blank cells in this selected range are the rows you want to delete.

4) Press the F5 key on your keyboard (or select Edit, Goto).

5) Click the Special... button.

6) Click the Blanks option and click OK. This will select all blank cells in the range you had previously selected.

7) Now choose Edit, Delete, select the Entire Row option and click OK.

8) I think this would do your requirement, if you still want to copy, select all the cells and copy to other cells.

Comment: Thanks Toms, This will work however I have A1:B100 pulling the data from a formula, I believe this will remove my formula :( ... I'm using =IF(Sheet1!D11="YES",Sheet1!A11, "") ... Thats in A1 then I copied it down to A100 and so on for B.